# Alignment of 'answerer' / 'asker' in flagging summary

Tags: feature-request, design, flag-history

The name of the 'answerer' looks to be too far to the right on the 'Flaggin Summary' page.

[flagging summary alignment http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/258/styling.png](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/258/styling.png)

It isn't really too far to the right from a technical view, but from a designer view it looks strange. The thing that makes it look strange is the 'header' with the title in it just above it.